# What is the proper way to bundle assets with an NPM module?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, svg

I have a library, let's call it `my-lib`. The packaged code contains some JS and type declarations for that code in `/dist`, as well as a number of SVG files in `/assets`:

```
my-lib
├── assets
│   ├── a.svg
│   ├── b.svg
├── dist
│   ├── index.d.ts
│   ├── index.mjs
│   ├── index.umd.js
├── LICENSE
├── package.json
```

My intention is to have the JS modules exported on the root of the package, `my-lib`, with the assets importable from `my-lib/assets` (when using an appropriate plugin for the user's framework and bundler, E.G. `vite-plugin-svgr` for React+Vite). This seems to work by default in a `create-react-app` project with Webpack using `import { ReactComponent as A } from "my-lib/assets/a.svg";` and the right declaration file to appease TypeScript, but in a Vite project ends up throwing errors:

```
[vite] Internal server error: Missing "./assets/a.svg" export in "my-lib" package
```

The important bits of my `package.json`:

```json
// package.json
{
  "main": "./dist/index.umd.js",
  "module": "./dist/index.mjs",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "./dist",
    "./assets"
  ],
  // ...rest
}
```

Are there specific fields to use for non-JS assets in `package.json`? Is this simply an issue with bundler config?

[Minimum reproducible example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-ey5ykg?file=src%2Fvite-env.d.ts,src%2FApp.tsx&terminal=dev)